# Back out of a component when it is conditionally rendered React Native

Tags: react-native

I Understand `StackNavigator` comes with back functionality.

**Problem**

I have a `TabNavigator` allowing 4 components to be viewed. Each one renders fine. One of those components has a button inside of it. This button loads a PDF on the screen. When this PDF is loaded into the screen it leaves no way for the user to back out to the initial component they were viewing.

**Questions**

How can I allow the user to back out of the PDF once rendered on the screen using header like back button functionality?

Is using `StackNavigator` for one button that loads a PDF my only option here?

In this image you can see I was able to make a header component with a back button inside of it. Now I can't come up with a way to back out of the PDF.

I Realize I can put this header on every component and then conditionally render the button to toggle the PDF, but I am hoping there is another way to tap into the stack without having to use `StackNavigator` when I am using a `TabNavigator`.

Image of PDF Rendered,

[image]

**Code Example**

There are 4 tabs, Login is the first component loaded, and the other three tabs are navigted to through `BottomTabNav`

The About component has a Button inside of it which conditionally renders the PDF. When you click it, it loads the PDF and uses a ternary to show About or PDF based on toggling the state of `this.state.pdf`
*Tab Navigation*

```
const BottomTabNav = TabNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Register: { screen: Register },
    Contact: { screen: Contact },
    About: { screen: About },
}, {

    tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
        bottomNavigationOptions: {
            labelColor: 'white',
            rippleColor: 'white',
            tabs: {
                Login: {
                    barBackgroundColor: '#37474F',
                    icon: <Icon size={24} color="white" name="user-circle-o" />,
                },
                Register: {
                    barBackgroundColor: '#464949',
                    icon: <Icon size={24} color="white" name="address-book" />,
                },
                Contact: {
                    barBackgroundColor: '#5D4037',
                    icon: <Icon size={24} color="white" name="phone-square" />,
                },
                About: {
                    barBackgroundColor: '#3E2723',
                    icon: <Icon size={24} color="white" name="info-circle" />,
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

export default BottomTabNav;
```

#

*About Component*

```
class About extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pdf: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const getView = this.state.pdf ? (<WelcomeKit />)
            : (
                <ScrollView>
                    <Card
                        title="Creative Designs From Creative Minds"
                        image={robot}
                        style={styles.container}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle} >
  Our professional team will design a responsive website or mobile app
  with your success in mind. We build mobile friendly sites that are
  search engine friendly.
                      </Text>
                        <Button
                            raised
                            icon={{ name: 'file-pdf-o', size: 32, type: 'font-awesome' }}
                            buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                            textStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
                            title="Welcome Kit"
                            onPress={() => this.setState({ pdf: !this.state.pdf })}
                        />
                    </Card>
                </ScrollView>
            );
        return (
            getView
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question to show how you render pdf and how does your navigator look like

Comment: I added the code for you at the bottom.

Comment: This is just a suggestion, I think since you already created a header for your component with the pdf you can create a new component which contains both header and the pfd component and you can use that in the screens you need. you can control the state of the component with passing a function to that component. Or you can take a look at modal . you can open up a modal on button click and then close the modal. react-navigation supports navigating to modal and going back.

Comment: A modal is actually a good idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI - your "back" button is really a "refresh" icon, so you'll probably want to change that